# Using prog1 to swap numbers

Tags: untagged

I want to understand the following that swaps the values of `i` and `j`.

```
(setq i (prog1 j (setq j i)))
```

The documentation says `FIRST` is evaluated first and is returned by `prog1`, then `BODY` is done later.  What is set first then, `i` or `j` ?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need to know. Please edit the question to make it clear what you need. Provide examples. Help us help you.

Comment: The question should be reopened. The question is about `prog1`. Its doc is what talks about argument `FIRST` etc. This is a good question, because this idiom is a useful one for swapping variable values. Such swapping is maybe the most common use of `prog1`. Can't answer it till it gets reopened, however.

Comment: How was this closed with only one Close vote? And yet it takes multiple votes to Reopen? See [this meta question](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/why-does-it-now-take-5-votes-to-close).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the doc of `prog1` tells you:

> `prog1` is a special form in `C source code`.
>
> `(prog1 FIRST BODY...)`
>
> Eval `FIRST` and `BODY` sequentially; return value from `FIRST`.
>
> The value of `FIRST` is saved during the evaluation of the remaining args,
> whose values are discarded.

"Sequentially" means first `FIRST` is evaluated, then each of the forms in `BODY...`. That's the order of evaluation. After all of that evaluation the value of `FIRST` is returned. That's all there is to it.

In your example:

```lisp
(setq i (prog1 j (setq j i)))
```

in `(prog1 j (setq j i)`, `FIRST` is `j`, and `BODY` is `(setq j i)`.

However in the overall sexp, `(setq i ...)` is first evaluated. `setq` doesn't evaluate its first arg, `i`, so the first thing evaluated is the `(prog1 ...)` sexp.

In that sexp the first thing evaluated is `j`. Then `(setq j i)` is evaluated, which evaluates `i` and sets `j` to that value of `i`. So `j` was evaluated first, then `j` was set to the value of `i`.

But the initial value of `j`, the result of the first evaluation, is what `prog1` returns. And then the overall sexp sets the value of `i` to that initial value of `j`. So `j` gets the initial value of `i` and `i` gets the initial value of `j`. All thanks to `prog1`.

---

See also my answer to your question about swapping characters in a string in [help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2023-07/msg00418.html):

Comment: "And then the overall sexp sets the value of `i` to that initial value of `i`."  Either I'm confused by the last paragraph (the rest of the description is clear) or the last variable in the quoted sentence should be changed to `j`.

Comment: @Y.E.: Typo (corrected). It should say "the overall sexp sets the value of i to that initial value of j." Thanks for noticing this.